# Maximum length of WPF .net exe filename

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-7

We had a situation when the file name of WPF .net 4.0 exe exceeds 47(51 including .exe extension) the exe is not working. It simply says stopped working.

The issue is there even if we put the file in side c:\ which means this is not windows limit.

Anybody came across a situation like this.

The issue solved by renaming the exe file with abbreviations. But would like to know why it happens.

Thanks in Advance
Joy

---

From Comments

Its the normal stopped working dialog.In the problem details it says:

> Problem signature: Problem Event Name: BEX Application Name: ABCEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV.exe Application Version: 1.0.0.0 Application Timestamp: 50e559e0 Fault Module Name: igdumd32.dll Fault Module Version: 8.15.10.1995 Fault Module Timestamp: 4af4b4e4 Exception Offset: 00014fe6 Exception Code: c0000409 Exception Data: 00000000 OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4 Locale ID: 1033 Additional Information 1: 1d75 Additional Information 2: 1d7537ede8bee0a1d08a5f0d2036cc52

Comment: What does it actually say? Care to post a screenshot?

Comment: Its the normal stopped working dialog.In the problem details it says Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: BEX
  Application Name: ABCEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV.exe
  Application Version: 1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 50e559e0
  Fault Module Name: igdumd32.dll
  Fault Module Version: 8.15.10.1995
  Fault Module Timestamp: 4af4b4e4
  Exception Offset: 00014fe6
  Exception Code: c0000409
  Exception Data: 00000000
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 1d75
  Additional Information 2: 1d7537ede8bee0a1d08a5f0d2036cc52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a stack buffer overflow in igdumd32.dll. Congratulations. You've just found out the hard way that Intel suck at writing good secure code.

Other than the fact that the Intel Graphics Accelerator dll that your graphics card vendor is helpfully shoving into your process and then stack overflowing when you give it a long module name, there is no limit to the length of a WPF filename, other than the usual Windows restriction of MAX_PATH.

Comment: Thanks...Really interesting ..Does this means if I try this in a AMD machine the issue will not occur? Or is it related with Intel graphics card which will not occur in other graphics cards?

Comment: igdumd32.dll is part of the Intel Graphics driver, not part of the Intel CPU chipset.